# Applinks meta tags not working on facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, applinks

I have gone though the documentation from both facebook and applinks.org a few times already but applinks are not working from the facebook android app. Clicking a link directly with the urlscheme for my app successfully opens the app. But when I share a web link to my newsfeed and click it from the fb app it opens a browser window instead of the app. Additionally facebook ograph debugger cannot see my meta tags.

Below is a sample html snippet containing:

> <!DOCTYPE html> 
>   <html> <head> <title>   Huambo:
>   Trinta mil bois vão ser vacinados no município da Caála
>   </title><meta name="fb:app_id"
>   content="862082893" /><meta
>   name="og:site_name" content="Noticias de Angola"
>   /><meta name="al:android:url"
>   content="ideiabasenoticiasdeangola://article/36417"
>   /><meta name="al:android:package"
>   content="com.ideiabase.noticiasdeangola" /><meta
>   name="al:android:app_name" content="Noticias de
>   Angola" /><meta name="al:ios:url"
>   content="ideiabasenoticiasdeangola://article/36417"
>   /><meta name="al:ios:app_store_id"
>   content="862082893" /><meta
>   name="al:ios:app_name" content="Noticias de
>   Angola" /><meta name="og:title"
>   content="Huambo: Trinta mil bois vão ser vacinados no
>   município da Caála" /><meta
>   name="og:image"
>   content="http://cdn1.portalangop.co.ao/angola/pt_pt/files/highlight/2014/9/42/0,319a87a5-95c8-470d-acae-fd27d53e3ac1--r--NjQweDM0Mw==.jpg&quot;
>   /><meta name="og:description"
>   content="Caála- Trinta mil cabeças de gado bovino
>   vão ser vacinadas contra o carbúnculo externo, interno,
>   dermatite nodular e peripneumonia contagiosa, no município da
>   Caála, província do Huambo, pelos serviços
>   veterinários.
>
> , A campanha de vacinação aberta hoje visa contrapor ao
>   surto de carbúnculo que est" /></head> <body>...

A live version of this is available here: [Sample article not working](http://news.ideiabase.com/article/36417)
Can you see anything wrong with the meta tags I am using?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. I thought I should share the answer.

When generating meta tags using asp.net they are generated using the format:

```
<meta name="al:android:url" content="ideiabasenoticiasdeangola://article/36417" />
```

Facebook and others expect:

```
<meta property="al:android:url" content="ideiabasenoticiasdeangola://article/36417" />
```

So the problem was that I was using the meta tag name attribute rather than the property attribute

Comment: Hi, what is the app id for chrome webbrowser, as i want to open a webpage in chrome from the facebook web browser, TIA